# How to format a string with date/time and timezone to account for the timezone php

Tags: php, datetime

I have an online calendar that I retrieve appointments from an API that includes the date, time and timezone in the following format "2017-02-04T13:00:00-0800," where 13:00 would be the proper time for the appointment, but when I convert the above into a date, which I do in the following manner,

```
  $stringtoTime = strtotime($times->time);
        $time = date('h:i A', $stringtoTime);
```

it comes up with a time 8 hours ahead of when the appointment is supposed to be. I know I have to account for the timezone somehow, but I am unsure of how to do that, as I kind of thought that strtotime would do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO', '2017-02-04T13:00:00-0800');
$time = $dateTime->format('h:i A');
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help! Worked perfectly for me.